# Is it possible to create unique secondary index in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

From what I read, I could not see any option of specifying the uniqueness constraint. I wanted to know whether it is possible ? Changing the column to primary key will require changing some other tables as well. That is why I am asking if it is possible to have a unique secondary index ?

Answer (score 2):

The [materialized views](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) feature in Cassandra 3.0 is meant to help with this problem.  You can create a materialized view on a secondary column that is unique such that you can then query the view with that column as the primary key.

There are some [limitations](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/understanding-materialized-views) with using this feature, as Cassandra has to do a lot of book keeping under the hood for you in order to keep the materialized view up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible.  The problem is that it is going to perform terribly.

Cassandra will create a table referencing each indexed value and row behind the scenes.  Each node will store its own part of the index locally.  So your index will basically have as many rows as your original table, except it won't be distributed.

That last part is key.  When you query that index, you will introduce network latency into the equation, as every node will need to be queried to see if it contains the indexed value.

That's why secondary indexes suck.  And high cardinality indexes suck even more.  This solution fails in a distributed environment because it does not scale.

Apple's Richard Low wrote a great article on this subject:  [The Sweet Spot for Cassandra Secondary Indexing](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77).  Give that a read.

Comment: I get your point. The situation I am currently facing is that we are using Cassandra as our only datastore for all the tables. There are certain tables which will have millions of rows but this table that I am talking about is not going to have more than 1000 rows. So, what I am trying to understand is that whether it is good practice to keep this table in cassandra only and have secondary index on the columns I need to query on or move such tables to some other data store ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Uniqueness on a column is not supported in Cassandra, there are [lightweight transactions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_ltweight_transaction_t.html) in v2 which work on the row level - this block writes to an existing key, otherwise it will be overwritten (i.e. uniqueness is part of being a primary key obviously). These do not apply to column values.

**BUT** you could implement this using **application logic** in the client...

- Create an additional table where the key is the column value
- Modify write operation to first query for the column value in the new table

  - If already exists (using lightweight transactions or a simple read) , block the insert of a new row to the other table (so, each write/update/delete of original table is tied to the column values table).
  - Else block write...
- To get the join/where functionality create an index on the column value (in original table).

Ugly, and doesn't work if clients decide to ignore the contract, but otherwise works, and should be pretty fast too if it's such a small table.