# In Cassandra, how to manage a writable column with unique value

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I am designing a schema for the following use case:

1. The object that we want to save to the DB contains 3 attribute(type, name, ID).
2. Make sure that the combination of (type, name) is unique.
3. Make sure that the ID is unique.
4. Find a row by (type, name).
5. Find a row by ID.
6. List all rows with given type.
7. delete a row by its (type, name).
8. Update the name of the row. After update, the type and ID shouldn't change and the name should still be unique, i.e., type and name are not updatable.
9. Create a row by type, name, and ID.
10. All the create/get/list/update/delete requests can come from different nodes. Within the same node, the request can come from different service. The number of nodes is less than 1000.
11. The number of rows is relatively small(worst case 12000, usually much less than 1000) and most of the operations are get/list. The read performance is not important.

I have tried:

1. We tried PRIMARY KEY (type, name). In this case, feature 8 is not possible as name is part of the primary key, and hence is not updatable.
2. We tried PRIMARY KEY (type, ID) or (ID) only. Cassandra doesn't allow put UNIQUE constraints on columns.

   i. If I do a read then write, there are potential race condition between two operations. Feature 10 is not satisfied.
   ii. I was also looking at the BATCH operations as it is said to be atomic and isolated on single partition. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html However the description for isolation "Isolation ensures that partial insertion or updates are not accessed until all operations are complete." is different from the definition of isolation for traditional DBs. If the Cassandra DB blocks all other Read/Write operations, then this is good for the use case. If it is not, the bottom line is that the BATCH operation blocks all other Write operations. Can anyone explain the actual isolation level of batch operation on single partition?
3. I found a thread says that using MATERIALIZED VIEW can be used to enforce the uniqueness of a secondary index. [Is it possible to create unique secondary index in Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769232/is-it-possible-to-create-unique-secondary-index-in-cassandra). To make sure the uniqueness of (type, name), the primary key for the materialized view should be (type, name) and ID shouldn't be part of it. Then if cannot be part of the table primary key according to the restriction: materialized view must "include all of the source table's primary keys in the materialized view's primary key." https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateMV.html. However, if we want to support feature 8, name cannot be part of the table primary key. Then there is no solution for it.

I want to have a solution for all those features, but none of my PoC meets all the requirement. If you have any idea on enforcing uniqueness, enforcing write isolation, and/or any better solution and thoughts, please put it into the comments.